# Streaming Video Recommendations

Tags: flash, iis-7, asp-classic, video-streaming

I'm trying to find a viable option for streaming flash video for most browsers.

The setup we have no is a Server 2008/IIS server using ASP. Our site gets somewhere in the neighborhood of 1,200 hits a day, and the videos wouldn't likely be watched more than a hundred or so times a day, at most.

Still, that said we have about 20gb/~100 videos from various speaking engagements that are about an hour long or so, and our main goal is to make them streamed, so that users don't need to wait for progressive downloads to jump around in the video.

I've read a bit about http streaming, and if that's doable I'd like to hear a reliable method to use; otherwise what sort of server software could we purchase to use, preferably on the same server to stream our videos to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short [article on http streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming).

I have actually found the [Adobe Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) a good and reasonably affordable solution.

You might also want to check out some third company streaming hosts - depending on the size of your company and the actual traffic you expect, the cost/benefit ratio of outsourcing can be better than when you're setting up and maintaining a server in-house.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those resources!